# What kind of error codes should a repository return to a RESTful Web API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

When I look at Microsofts sample about the **repository pattern** its of course a total simple sample nothing to do with the real world requirements - as always...-

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

The Repository Add/Del/Update methods return Void - nothing -

On the other side when someone uses my RESTful Web API I want to offer things like

`NotFound()` if the deletion of a record did not do anything

`OK()` If the deletion was successful

Same for Update method.

What do you use in your real world projects as return types for your repositories to let the caller know what really happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major options:

1. Treat situations like NotFound as exceptional. Specify exception types that will be thrown by your repository in situations where the object you meant to delete wasn't there. If you choose this option, then you can have a very general exception-catching handler at the Web API layer that knows what sort of response these exceptions should translate to.
2. Change the repository interface to return an [Optional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) error value or a [Sum Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) representing all the possible results of the call to that method. This requires the method calling into the repository to decide what to do in each scenario, but it allows more flexibility in handling scenarios as well. (e.g. Perhaps you want `DeletePerson` to return NotFound if the person itself wasn't there, but if no data is present when you use a different repository to clean up some related data, you want to use a different return type?)

What you should *avoid* is having the Repository layer return some kind of HTTP-oriented response code.

Comment: I like your first approach above all to see NotFound as exceptional. Thus I will create a NotFoundException class and connect this with an NotFoundExceptionFilterAttribute :-) Thanks!

Comment: @Elisa: One more thing you may want to consider, in that case, is to provide a way to not throw an exception as well--maybe a `TryDelete()` method, which either returns a boolean or simply does nothing if the item isn't there. You're likely to run into situations where you don't care if the thing has already been deleted, and I don't recommend catching and eating exceptions in those cases.

Comment: Btw. what do you return where there happend no exception? Void? For Create I have to return the entity - because of the new created Id - but for update/delete/ATTACH/DETACH ? The two last are just a relation removal actually kind of HTTP Patch.

Comment: @Elisa: Yeah, if you're going to say that operations that don't work for some reason are all represented by exceptions, then your actual return type should be the same as it would be if you didn't care about those exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

> What do you use in your real world projects as return types for your repositories to let the caller know what really happened?

A "result object". A simple version could look like this:

```
public class RepositoryActionResult
{
    public int RecordsAffected { get; set; }        
}
```

Then you can set that from your repository methods and handle the results from calling code appropriately, without using exceptions for control flow.

You can make this class as complex as you want, depending on your requirements.

Comment: RecordsAffected is not useful outside the repository if you ask me. The SaveChanges return 3 if you update 3 tables each one row. The updates could still be wrong. I already had it that way: int recordsAffected = context.SaveChanges() I do not like it to count tables... to return the insert entity Or null in an error case.